# Jsf Datatable jQuery selected indexes return Object as value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jsf, bootsfaces

i am currently trying to get the value of a cell in my datatable but i always get an Object object as value and i cant understand why.

Maybe someone can explain me what is going on.

```
onselect="console.log($.isArray(indexes) + ' ' + $.type(indexes)); $.each(indexes, function(index, value) {console.log(index + ': ' + value.toString());});"
```

that is my call.

And that is my column :

```
<c:forEach var="day" items="#{scheduleView.day_array}">
  <b:dataTableColumn value="#{worker.schedule[day].name}" label="#{day.dayOfMonth}" onclick="console.log('HALLO')" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i learned how to check it now xD,

```
$.each(value, function(key, element) {console.log('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element);})
```

with this you can check the properties of the object.